# How to get a good overview of projects using TFS 2012

Tags: scrum, agile, team-management, reporting, tfs

My team are just evaluating a move to a more agile process and one of the questions that has arisen is how best to track...

- Projects (upcoming, in progress, completed)
- Team capacity

I'm hoping to find an electronic method that can be made visible to other people within the business and also possibly displayed on a big plasma tv or projector.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas that would point me in the right direction?

Comment: This MSDN article gives the basics of Agile under TFS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189203.aspx

Comment: What have you already tried or considered? Why are those things not working for you?

Comment: We've tried using pure TFS but it doesn't work well for "high level" views of all projects currently in progress/waiting/etc.  TFS works well "in the dev team" and for dealing with per-project stakeholders ... but when it comes to showing the business higher ups an overview of all projects currently in the queue or in progress etc it's not so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly suggest updating to TFS 2013. They've implemented agile portfolio management tools, with 7 levels of work items. It is currently in preview, but it is fully supported and "go-live".

Here's a good site outlining the new features
[VS 2013](http://nakedalm.com/get-visual-studio-2013-team-foundation-server-while-its-hot/)

The 2012 alternative is to nest PBI's inside of PBI's, and manipulate area paths to simulate various levels (without creating custom work item types for epics/visions etc). I've implemented this solution before, but it can get rather confusing and there are some odd things that happen when nesting PBI's.

Also, if you just want to display status you can use SSRS to generate reports of the TFS warehouse (and/or cube). Depending on how your TFS Server is being used (multiple team project collections, multiple team projects), this has varying degrees of difficulty. 
[VS 2012 Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee921483.aspx)

Unfortunately, it is difficult to be more specific without more specific information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a tool that makes TFS more user friendly, [Eylean](http://www.eylean.com/tfs?utm_source=website&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=DMStack) could be a great option. It offers a two way integration with TFS and represents the tasks in a clear task board that can be projected on a big plasma tv or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com) product management in TFS 2012.

Regards

P.S I am the product owner of Urban Turtle.